# KeyError while trying to read from Python dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

Hi I am new to Python and I am trying to read from a csv file using the following code

```
dataFrame = pd.read_csv(path, header=None)

X = dataFrame.loc[:,1:93]
y = dataFrame.loc[:,94]
print(X)
print(y)
```

But I get the following error

> KeyError: 'the label [94] is not in the [columns]'

But when I copy the contents of same csv file into another and run the code, it works.. Can anyone help me with this as I cannot keep on copying the csv files as there are huge number of files.

The csv file to be read in 'path' has been created using the following code

```
criterion = dataFrame[93].map(lambda x: x==some_value)
with open(temp_file, 'a') as f:
                dataFrame[criterion2].to_csv(f, sep='\t', encoding='utf-8',header=False)
```

Comment: why do you open `temp_file` for appending? Wouldn't that suggest there is already content in the file?

Comment: Yes actually there is a content in the temp file which is created using teh code  dataFrame[criterion1].to_csv(temp_file, sep='\t', encoding='utf-8',header=False)

Comment: ok, what do you mean by "copy the contents of the same csv file into another" ? I assume you do not mean programmably since then I see no reason it would be a pain, does it still work when copying the file through python?

Comment: I copied the contents manually to another csv file.... What i want programmably is to create some csv files and manipulate the contents from it... As of now I created csv files but I am not able to read from it programically.. So I copied contents from it to another csv manually and did the manipulations

Comment: Let me see if I understand this correctly: your python program creates a csv file, you open that file up in notepad / etc, copy the entire file and paste it into another (previously blank) file and then when you use the directly created file it fails but the one that was copied worked?  I do not see how that could happen.

Comment: Yes your interpretation is correct. I tried to copy the entire csv file to another by using python code also.. Then the new file created still does'nt work. So  I guess there is some  trailing null character or something in the file created which is interfering with its manipulation. When I copy it manually it is cleared of it thus it works. How can  I get rid of that?

Comment: I have a strong feeling that finding a way to only call `.to_csv` once without then opening the file for appending would fix the issue, however I can't help there unless you provide that section of your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113700/discussion-between-athira-and-tadhg-mcdonald-jensen).

Comment: Seems to me this could be BOM related pandas issue. Try doing,    `encoding = 'utf-8-sig'`.

Comment: @NickilMaveli I tried doing 'utf-8-sig' but it doesnt work ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem has been solved.. Actually my columns in csv were getting read as a single column with /t appended. So I used delimiter specification as follows
`dataFrame = pd.read_csv(temp_file,sep=', ', delimiter='\t')`
the code works now.